# Grails throws Exception while upload csv to save domain object for existing id

Tags: csv, grails, file-upload, groovy, email-validation

I am getting grails exception while uploading a csv file. This csv file have around 50 records. This upload functionality is save a record on existing record if the other fields are differ from existing unique field base.

The exception is as follows.

```
Grails Runtime Exception
Error Details
Message: 
Caused by: Executing action [upload] of controller [com.tr.WeeklyUploadController] caused exception: Runtime error executing action 
Class: Unknown 
At Line: [-1] 
Code Snippet:

Stack Trace

org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.exceptions.ControllerExecutionException: Executing action [upload] of controller [com.tr.WeeklyUploadController]  caused exception: Runtime error executing action

at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:53)
at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.java:62)
at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.SecurityRequestHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityRequestHolderFilter.java:59)
at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.DebugFilter.invokeWithWrappedRequest(DebugFilter.java:102)
at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.DebugFilter.doFilter(DebugFilter.java:69)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.exceptions.ControllerExecutionException: Runtime error executing action

... 8 more

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

... 8 more

Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError

at java.util.regex.Pattern$7.isSatisfiedBy(Pattern.java:5273)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$7.isSatisfiedBy(Pattern.java:5273)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$7.isSatisfiedBy(Pattern.java:5273)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$7.isSatisfiedBy(Pattern.java:5273)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$7.isSatisfiedBy(Pattern.java:5273)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$7.isSatisfiedBy(Pattern.java:5273)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$7.isSatisfiedBy(Pattern.java:5273)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$7.isSatisfiedBy(Pattern.java:5273)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$7.isSatisfiedBy(Pattern.java:5273)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$7.isSatisfiedBy(Pattern.java:5273)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$7.isSatisfiedBy(Pattern.java:5273)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$7.isSatisfiedBy(Pattern.java:5273)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$7.isSatisfiedBy(Pattern.java:5273)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$7.isSatisfiedBy(Pattern.java:5273)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$7.isSatisfiedBy(Pattern.java:5273)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$CharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3778)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.match(Pattern.java:4606)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4660)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4787)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4719)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BranchConn.match(Pattern.java:4570)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$CharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3779)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.match(Pattern.java:4606)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4660)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4787)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4719)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BranchConn.match(Pattern.java:4570)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$CharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3779)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.match(Pattern.java:4606)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4660)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4787)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4719)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BranchConn.match(Pattern.java:4570)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$CharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3779)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.match(Pattern.java:4606)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4660)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4787)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4719)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BranchConn.match(Pattern.java:4570)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$CharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3779)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.match(Pattern.java:4606)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4660)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4787)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4719)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BranchConn.match(Pattern.java:4570)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$CharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3779)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.match(Pattern.java:4606)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4660)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.matchInit(Pattern.java:4803)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Prolog.match(Pattern.java:4743)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.match(Pattern.java:4606)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4660)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4281)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4236)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Begin.match(Pattern.java:3527)
at java.util.regex.Matcher.match(Matcher.java:1270)
at java.util.regex.Matcher.matches(Matcher.java:604)
at org.apache.commons.validator.routines.EmailValidator.isValidUser(EmailValidator.java:162)
at org.apache.commons.validator.routines.EmailValidator.isValid(EmailValidator.java:122)
```

If anybody reply its a great help. The exception throws one few records from CSV file. Few are able to update.

Comment: You don't encourage to help with these words: _It is urgent to push into production the application._

Comment: Show us your code